# kdb update column and perform a sort based on group and then update another column based on date rank

Tags: kdb

I have a table below eg,

1. how do I sort date in asc order and for those sorted date we want expiration_date to be sorted in asc order.
2. once we do that we want to add symbology to sym column,
   so nearest expiry date will be denoted ESc1! and then second nearest will be ESc2!
3. we should rollover to the next contract on expiry date - 1, so the day before expiration we will change ESc2! will change to ESc1!

```
  date      sym   expiration_date
2021-11-01  ES1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-01  ES2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-01  ES3!  2022-06-17
2021-11-02  ES1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-02  ES2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-02  ES3!  2022-06-17
2021-11-03  ES1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-03  ES2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-03  ES3!  2022-06-17
2021-11-12  ES1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-12  ES2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-12  ES3!  2022-12-16
2021-11-12  ES4!  2022-06-17
2021-11-15  ES1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-15  ES2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-16  ES1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-16  ES2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-16  ES3!  2022-06-17
```

Expected Output

```
  date      sym   expiration_date
2021-11-01  ES1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-01  ES2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-01  ES3!  2022-06-17
2021-11-01  ESc1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-01  ESc2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-01  ESc3!  2022-06-17
2021-11-02  ES1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-02  ES2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-02  ES3!  2022-06-17
2021-11-02  ESc1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-02  ESc2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-02  ESc3!  2022-06-17
2021-11-03  ES1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-03  ES2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-03  ES3!  2022-06-17
2021-11-03  ESc1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-03  ESc2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-03  ESc3!  2022-06-17
2021-11-12  ES1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-12  ES2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-12  ES3!  2022-12-16
2021-11-12  ES4!  2022-06-17
2021-11-12  ESc1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-12  ESc2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-12  ESc3!  2022-06-17
2021-11-12  ESc4!  2022-12-16
2021-11-15  ES1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-15  ES2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-15  ESc1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-15  ESc2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-16  ES1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-16  ES2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-16  ES3!  2022-06-17
2021-11-16  ESc1!  2021-12-17
2021-11-16  ESc2!  2022-03-18
2021-11-16  ESc3!  2022-06-17
```

Comment: Are the 2021.11.02 entries in the expected output correct? It seems to be the only date with no ESc* entries.

Comment: good spot, that was a typo. I had updated it. It should have ESc*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
ungroup select
    sym:{ES:`$"ES",/:string[1+til count?[(.z.d-1)=a 0;1_a;a:asc x]],\:"!";
        ES,`${ssr[string x;"ES";"ESc"]}each ES}expiration_date,
    {raze 2#enlist?[(.z.d-1)=a 0;1_a;a:asc x]}expiration_date
        by date from tbl
```

Edit: Update code for part 3 of task.

Here the code by date sorts the tbl by date first, then using the logic of asc expiration_date, we can check if the first expiration date equals yesterday. If so, we drop that from the list.

Using the same check for the sym col we know the count of expiration_date for each date so we can apply our function of ES* and ESc*.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for Maurice, thank you!

not sure if your expected output is correct as pointed out by Cathal. -> that was a typo. I had updated it.

 don't quite understand part 3 of your task  -> Basically what we want to do is
If expiration_date=.z.d-1 then delete that row from resultset and recalculate everything again by giving new symbology.

Comment: Say for sym=ESc1!, the expiration_date=2021.01.12, and todays date is 2021.01.11 and for sym=ESc2!, the expiration_date=2021.03.15.
Then we will delete ESc1 from resultset and now after deleting ESc1 then new ESc1 will now be come ESc2

Comment: @HAK I have updated the code to include part 3 of the task now and also combined everything into a single query. I hope it works.

Comment: Looks good now, thanks Maurice!

Comment: Maurice, after point 3, how do we achieve point 4?
Point 3: we should rollover to the next contract on expiry date - 1, so the day before expiration we will change ESc2! will change to ESc1!
Point 4: Once ESc2! symbol will change to ESc1!, we want the sym ESc1! to set ESc0! so that it will not occur again. Once the sym is set to rank 1 and then switched - we dont want that rank1 symbol to be rank1 or rank2 again. we want it to set to rank zero permanently once it flipped.

Comment: @HAK, not sure i follow your logic, could you edit the question to provide more explanation and your expected output? Point 3: delete ESc1, ESc2 becomes new ESc1. Point 4: new ESc1 becomes ESc0 immediately? Is that what you want?

Comment: okay, try looking at the 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72145825/kdb-once-the-symbol-flipped-over-then-it-should-not-flipped-back-and-forth

Comment: basically from the table we want to set the rank to 1 which has most volume per day, rank2 to 2nd most highest and so on. If say VXZ4 has highest volume for 1st to 3rd and on 4th VXZ4 rollover over to VXG8. We want the VXZ4 rank to set 0 from 4th onwards. This way we are not flipping back and forth