# kdb+ once the symbol flipped over, then it should not flipped back and forth

Tags: kdb

To generate the below sample data use below code.

```
//To create a sample table
tdate:2010.01.01+til 31
tmp:([]sdate:`date$();sym:`symbol$();name:`symbol$();volume:`float$();rollover:`boolean$();roll_rank:`int$());
{`tmp insert (x;`VXV2;`someName1;100.1;0b;1)} each tdate;
{`tmp insert (x;`VXJ2;`someName2;200.2;0b;1)} each tdate;
{`tmp insert (x;`VXG8;`someName3;300.3;0b;1)} each tdate;
{`tmp insert (x;`VXZ4;`someName4;400.4;0b;1)} each tdate;

//below steps are to generate/update sample data for testing to match desired dataset which we want to create a new logic
tmp:`sdate xasc `volume xdesc tmp;
tmp:update sums roll_rank by sdate from tmp;
tmp:update volume:500.4 from tmp where sdate=2010.01.04, sym=`VXG8;
```

```
This is how the tmp table looks like on tmp
select from tmp
```

[image]

```
This is how the aggregation looks like
select from tmp where volume=(max;volume) fby sdate
```

[image]

We want to perform our logic on (select from tmp) table.

1. As we see, the symbol VXZ4 was having max volume from 2010-01-01 to
   2010-01-03.
2. On 2010-01-04, the max volume that day was for VXG8.
3. Now we want from 2010-01-05 to 2010-01-31 the roll_rank:1 for symbol
   should be VXG8.
4. We want VXZ4 to be set to rollrank:0 for the period 2010-01-04 to 2010-01-31.
5. Once the rollrank is set to 0, it cannot be flipped over. eg, the symbol VXZ4 flipped to VXG8
6. On 2010-01-04, then in futures dates we cannot have VXZ4 appearing again in symbol list
   and we want it to set as roll_rank:0 that means we dont have to see it again.
7. We want to updated roll_rank based on the highest volume.

```
tmp:`sdate xasc `volume xdesc tmp;
tmp:update sums roll_rank by sdate from tmp;
```

Expected Output is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that your `rollover` and `roll_rank` columns are *instrumental* to the Expected Output and not required in it.

---

TL;DR – find cumulative maxima; eliminate recurrences; upsert into an empty table; fill nulls

---

We’ll add two extra lines to your script: one to test the constraint described in your last comment; the other to check we find the *current* and not the first maximum for the leading symbol. We’ll also sort `tmp` *after* the updates to ensure it reflects them. So the script ends:

```
//below steps are to generate/update sample data for testing 
// to match desired dataset which we want to create a new logic
tmp:update volume:500.4 from tmp where sdate=2010.01.04, sym=`VXG8;
// find current not first maximum
tmp:update volume:600.6 from tmp where sdate=2010.01.05, sym=`VXG8;  
// confirm VXZ4 cannot recur
tmp:update volume:700.7 from tmp where sdate=2010.01.06, sym=`VXZ4;  
tmp:`sdate xasc `volume xdesc tmp; 
/ tmp:update sums roll_rank by sdate from tmp;
```

The first step enlarges Terry Lynch’s answer. We select the rows where the maximum changes and also mark where the symbol changes.

```
q)show q:update rollover:differ sym from select sdate,sym,name,volume from tmp where differ maxs volume
sdate      sym  name      volume rollover
-----------------------------------------
2010.01.01 VXZ4 someName4 400.4  1
2010.01.04 VXG8 someName3 500.4  1
2010.01.05 VXG8 someName3 600.6  0
2010.01.06 VXZ4 someName4 700.7  1
```

The second step eliminates the last row of `q`, because `VXZ4` may not recur.

For this we use an ancient APL idiom for finding duplicates in a vector. In APL it’s `(⍳⍴x)≠x⍳x`, which translates easily into q as `(til count x)<>x?x`. And we key on `sdate`.

```
q)show r:1!delete from q where rollover and {(til count x)<>x?x}sym
sdate     | sym  name      volume rollover
----------| ------------------------------
2010.01.01| VXZ4 someName4 400.4  1
2010.01.04| VXG8 someName3 500.4  1
2010.01.05| VXG8 someName3 600.6  0
```

This is all we need in the result. The rest is just filler.

```
q)/ make a template table
q)s:1!flip`sdate`sym`name`volume!flip tdate,\:(`;`;0n)
q) and fill in the gaps
q)fills s upsert delete rollover from r
sdate     | sym  name      volume
----------| ---------------------
2010.01.01| VXZ4 someName4 400.4
2010.01.02| VXZ4 someName4 400.4
2010.01.03| VXZ4 someName4 400.4
2010.01.04| VXG8 someName3 500.4
2010.01.05| VXG8 someName3 600.6
2010.01.06| VXG8 someName3 600.6
2010.01.07| VXG8 someName3 600.6
2010.01.08| VXG8 someName3 600.6
2010.01.09| VXG8 someName3 600.6
2010.01.10| VXG8 someName3 600.6
2010.01.11| VXG8 someName3 600.6
2010.01.12| VXG8 someName3 600.6
..
```

Comment: Thank you SJT, really appreciate your detailed solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear how you expect your output data to look (since your output screenshot is itself an aggregation) but this might get you on the right track.

It sounds like you just need to keep a mapping of the front-month symbols.

```
front_month:`s#exec sdate!sym from tmp where differ maxs volume;
q)front_month
2010.01.01| VXZ4
2010.01.04| VXG8
```

You can add more logic to this selection as required.

Then in your tmp table you lookup the front-month symbols on a per-date basis and choose the rows where the symbol is the front month symbol

```
q)update rollover:differ sym from select from tmp where sym=front_month sdate
sdate      sym  name      volume rollover roll_rank
---------------------------------------------------
2010.01.01 VXZ4 someName4 400.4  1        1
2010.01.02 VXZ4 someName4 400.4  0        1
2010.01.03 VXZ4 someName4 400.4  0        1
2010.01.04 VXG8 someName3 500.4  1        2
2010.01.05 VXG8 someName3 300.3  0        2
2010.01.06 VXG8 someName3 300.3  0        2
2010.01.07 VXG8 someName3 300.3  0        2
...
```

Again, add more logic as required.

Comment: somewhat yes, basically  from the table (select from tmp) we want to set the rank to 1 which has most volume per day, rank2 to 2nd most highest and so on.
If say VXZ4 has highest volume for 1st to 3rd and on 4th VXZ4 rollover over to VXG8. We want the  VXZ4 rank to set 0 from 4th onwards. This way we are not flipping back and forth.

Comment: I am trying to create a continuous futures contract based on volume
say we have a 1 month sample data with each date have 10-15 records
we need to find the max volume for each date, rank them to rank 1 which has highest volume, rank 2 to 2nd highest volume

Comment: //perform rollover based on volume
    res1:`date xasc `volume xdesc res1;
//lets reset the rank after the sort is done so we can use sums
    res1:update roll_rank:1 from res1;
//calc the sorted roll rank
    res1:update sums roll_rank by date, root from res1;
//get the rollover sym
    res1:update rollover:differ sym from res1 where roll_rank=1;

Comment: here, VXZ4 was having max volume from 1st-3rd.
On 4th, the sym VXZ4 rolled over to VXG8 has it has maximum volume for that date.
On 5th, the sym VXZ4 has maximum volume, thus again the rollover happens from VXG8 to VXZ4 .  --> this we don't want to happen.

Comment: Once the symbol flips/rolls over to another sym, we dont want that symbol to be rank1 again in futures after rollover

Comment: If I’m following you, appending ``tmp:update volume:700.7 from tmp where sdate=2010.01.06, sym=`VXZ4;`` to your script would test that last condition.